# How to encode more user data into jwt token in Strapi cms

Tags: node.js, strapi

I fell in love in Strapi headless cms. It is an awesome tool reducing several days of effort of programming.

For some reason I need to add more user data into the default jwt token.

**How to add more user data into default jwt token**

Is this possible at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encryption of the data is done during the login.

If you want to add more data, you will have to customize the `connect` function of the Auth controller.

[This line](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js#L135) to be specific.

[Here](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/customization.html) is the documentation of how to customize plugins functions.

Comment: Does this still apply to Strapi v4? The links seem to be outdated.